# r.js -o build.js result is a big file

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette, amd, r.js

Which is 650kbs. The browser load it very slowy. No improvements at all. It's much better when is not compressed.

I'm using a lot of libreries and some legacy code, also r.js compile all the template html files that I'm using.

Any hints? 
Thanks.

My build.js is:

```
({
   mainConfigFile : "js/main.js",
   baseUrl : "js",
   name: "main",
   out: "dist/main.js"
})
```

Comment: it can't technically be larger than the source, unless your doing something wrong. can you post your minify configuration?

Comment: Added to the question – btw, is not larger than the source. The problem I think is that it's a BIG file and is more slower than more splitted files.

Comment: technically less http requests is faster. try to specify `minify: "uglify2"` to make it smaller, other than that, it just concatenates and minifies your code, so no magic is being done.

Comment: How about use two js files in your web site:
1. require.js.
2. main.js.
Or just do not use r.js, just uglify every single js file is ok.

For best practice, you can try Yeoman-Generators.